# Are protein powders unhealthy for a teen athlete?

Tags: protein, muscle-mass, muscle-gain, muscle-recovery, high-protein

I startet working out 5 months ago. Until now i havent used anything that didnt come from my kitchen table. Yesterday i ordered from bodybuilding.com a 5 lbs gold protein and 15 quest protein bars. Im a little hasty so this is after the decision question. Are they unhealthy for a growing teen. Btw im 18. Could they couse problems. My dad seems they will but still...?

Comment: Too much protein can cause problems. Without any information regarding your dietary habits it's impossible to provide meaningful advice. Chances are you're getting enough protein without supplementation, but judicious use of protein powders can be beneficial (e.g., as part of a recovery drink taken < 2h after your workout, but it should also include 2-3x grams of carbs). Unhealthy? Almost certainly not.

Answer (score 5):

No, protein supplements are made of whey protein, which is the liquid remaining after milk has been curdled and strained. It's not a synthetic product of any kind.

I haven't tried the Gold brand in particular, but I can see that it's being sold by some of the most reputable sites (including here in Norway), so I see no reason doubt its quality.

Your father is right to be concerned, because you hear stories about people **abusing supplements** all the time. But just to be clear, it's not protein powder that causes this. All of the scary stories are mostly surrounding those who abuse illegal or controlled substances.

Whey is as natural as milk itself, because... well, that's what it is.

Comment: To be complete, protein powders *can* be made of whey and normally are, but they're also made of casein, soy, pea, eggs, rice, and other sources.

Comment: @EricKaufman - You're absolutely right. I guess I should have been more clear about it, but I was speaking more on the Gold brand, and similar ones.